# Java: How to reference library dependencies *without* 'import' statement?

Tags: java, netbeans, import

I'm using NetBeans, and I am factoring out common classes into a library.  I want to refer to classes in the library.  I can do this easily enough by telling NetBeans that one project is dependent on another, the latter being a Java Library project.

The library project is called "ReVueLib". I have a folder there called "Stream", and in there is a class "StreamClient".  The following is an abridged version of what matters:

```
package Stream;
class StreamClient {
    public void StreamClient() {}
};
```

I have another project called "ReVueServer", and the main looks like this:

```
package revueserver;
import Stream.StreamClient;
public class ReVueServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class c = StreamClient.class;
        System.out.println(c.getName());
    }
};
```

Now if I run this, it works fine and prints out "Stream.StreamClient".  But say I want to refer to this class *without* the import.  The reason is that in another project, I want to subclass Network.StreamClient as a class called StreamClient.  This will help me to avoid refactoring a TON of existing code.  In other words, I'm taking advantage of the namespace separation to be able to subclass and reuse the old name.

Unfortunately, if I take out the import, "Stream.StreamClient" doesn't work, nor does "ReVueLib.Stream.StreamClient" or anything else I've tried.

What FQCN do I need to use in order to reference this library class without "import"ing it?

Comment: Use fully-qualified name of the class.

Answer (score 2):

The proper name of a class in a package includes full name of the package. The `import` statement lets you avoid writing the prefix, but that is a compile-time trick. That is why your program prints the fully qualified name `Stream.StreamClient`, even though your program referred to the class by its short name `StreamClient`.

You can always rewrite your program to use full names for all your classes:

```
Class c = Stream.StreamClient.class;
```

or even

```
java.lang.Class c = Stream.StreamClient.class;
```

Comment: From the sound of it, he also had Stream imported, so the compiler might have been getting confused. The code as *written* works, although "Stream" as a package name tends to violate most conventions.

Answer (score 2):

Stream.StreamClient is the FQCN and you should be able to remove the import and use that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a better explanation than "Doesn't work". Why doesn't this work?

```
package revueserver;
public class ReVueServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class c = Stream.StreamClient.class;
        System.out.println(c.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of good answers that I'll upvote.  It turns out that the question is bogus.  I had a naming conflict.  There was already a Stream class that I had forgotten to remove before trying to add a reference to a Stream namespace.  The class name took precedence over the external namespace.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot refer to a class API without importing it (by either import or explicity fully qualified reference). Ever. Thats set in stone.

I think your misconception is that you could just write "Stream.class" somewhere and depending on whats on the classpath it will work. Thats true only to a very limited extent. While you can replace the Stream.class with another class of the same *qualified* name and API (that is methods and referenced fields), classes are *always* referred by their qualified name (thats package + class name).

Your problem sounds more like you need dependency injection with a common API. That allows you to select different implementations *of the same API*.

This works generally by defining the API, either as an interface or as abstract class:

```
package my.common;

public interface MyAPI {
    public void doSomething();
}
```

Your program code can *only* operate on the defined interface and you will need the interface on the class path to compile and run.

You can then define any number of implementations of the interface anywhere you want:

```
package my.green;

public GreenAPI implements MyAPI {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("You reached green API");
    }
}
```

Finally, you program need to be injected with the information how to get to the implementation at runtime. In the simplest case this can be done by passing the class name as a parameter somewhere, there are also frameworks to do this:

```
package something;

import my.common.MyAPI;

public MyAPIUser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class<?> apiImpl = Class.forName("my.green.GreenAPI");
            MyAPI api = (MyAPI) apiImpl.newInstance();
            api.doSomething();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStakcTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thats, how the JRE manages to supply a common API for all JDBC drivers by the way.

Comment: You can absolutely refer to a class without importing it, simply by using the fully qualified name: 'java.util.Map someMap = new java.util.HashMap();' will work without any import statements. You would need that if, for example, you wanted to use two classes with the same name (i.e. java.util.List and java.awt.List)

Comment: @Torque Thats *not not importing it*. The resulting class file will have the exact same dependency as if you imported it. Its pure compiler sugar, it doesn't change squat about your runtime dependencies.

Comment: An import is *only* a compiler thing.  Using the FQCN means not having to import it.  Does the resulting bytecode look the same?  Yes.  But using the FQCN is *referencing* a class not *importing* it.

Comment: "Thats, how the JRE manages to supply a common API for all JDBC drivers by the way."

If you're referring to the `Class.forName()` call that hasn't been necessary since 1.4.  Otherwise that sentence makes no sense.

Comment: @evanchooly You're right if you *insist* on the exact meaning in the languge sense. But the point is dependency management, where referring and importing are the exact same thing. And in my reference to the JDBC driver I am referring to the *whole* pattern of *common API* with any number of implementations *optionally* present. And that Class.forName is still necessary if the driver doesn't implement JDBC 4.

Comment: Programming terms have precise meaning and so, yes, I "insist" on the exact meaning because words mean things.  And your JDBC comment still makes no sense but oh well.  I can't think of any driver that *doesn't* support JDBC 4 since that's been out over a decade now.

Comment: @evanchooly Well then insist. Just keep in mind that language is an imprecise thing to begin with - worse, individuals have slightly different ideas what things words mean. And jTDS still only supports JDBC3. And there are people who use it, too - well at least one.

Comment: SPI support in jtds:  http://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/code/HEAD/tree/branches/jTDS%201.3%20%28stable%29/src/META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver

Which is jdbc4.